# Max and min of $f(x,y)=(3x^2+2y^2-x|x|+2)^{3 \over 5}$ on $|x|+|y|\le1$

Tags: real-analysis

D is a compact and f is continuous so for Weierstrass global max and min exist.Because f(x,y)=f(-x,-y) can I study for y>0?

Comment: This is not true $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y).$

Comment: Did you intend to say $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$? If so, then you only need consider $y\ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: it is easy to see that $3x^{2}+2y^{2}-x|x|+2 >0$. It is enough to find the max and min without the power and this simplifies a lot. Next, it is enough to find the max and min for $x >0$ and $x \leq 0$ separately. This again simplifies the problem. Now you should find the problem much simpler.

Comment: So I found local  min in $(0,0),(-1/3,2/3),(-1/3,-2/3),(1/2,1/2),(1/2,-1/2)$.Where is the max?(0,0) is the global min

Comment: @user495707 No, need to find all local extrema. First consider $x>0$. Then $3x^{2}+2y^{2}-x^{2}+2=2x^{2}+2y^{2}+2$ can attain global maximum only when $x=1-|y|$ so you only have to maximize $2(1-|y|)^{2}+2y^{2}+2$ subject to $-1\leq y \leq 1$. The maximum value is $2$. Do a similar thing with $x<0$ and take the maximum of the two numbers you get.